# Setting axis x line* and axis y line* globally

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz, tikzplotlib

I have encountered a "problem" to which I was not yet able to find a solution. If one exports a figure with `tikzplotlib` or `matlab2tikz`, the lines

```
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
```

are inserted randomly - or at least it seems arbitrary to me - altering the "frame" of the figure. It's not that big of a deal to simply delete these lines of code in a tikzfigure, but it got me wondering... Is there a way to suppress these lines globally in the preamble of the document?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\figureheight}
\newlength{\figurewidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\figurewidth}{0.8\textwidth}
\setlength{\figureheight}{0.4\textwidth}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
at={(0\figurewidth,0\figureheight)},
scale only axis,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
every x tick/.append style={black},
xmin=0.04,
xmax=0.11,
xlabel={$x$},
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
every y tick/.append style={black},
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
ylabel={$y$},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
]
\addplot [color=red, line width=2.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0.04    0\\
0.05    0.05\\
0.06    0.12\\
0.07    0.3\\
0.08    0.6\\
0.09    0.8\\
0.10    0.95\\
0.11    1\\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting graph from the MWE:

[image]

Result with `axis x line*=bottom` and `axis y line*=left` commented out:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to "suppress" them, but you can *overwrite*/*overrule* them. To do so you can use the `every axis post` style to append the stuff you want. In this case this is `axis lines=box`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        every axis post/.append style={
            axis lines=box,
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
    ]
        \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked great!